# Contraction for "owe on"; would it be "owe'n" or "ow'n"?

Tags: contractions

What would the contraction for *owe on* be, *owe'n* or *ow'n*?

Comment: I've never heard "owe on" as an expression; can you give some context for its use?

Comment: @Martha: Confused me at first, and took me a while to think of an example.  I came up with: "How much do you still *owe on* that [item you used a loan to buy]?"

Comment: Surely the correct way of saying that would be: How much do you still owe ***for*** that car?

Comment: You won't get an answer on your terms, for the simple reason that English speakers don't use any such contraction. Unsurprisingly, when you consider how rarely you'd need it by comparison with the contractions I've used in this comment.

Answer (score 11):

There is no contraction for "owe on"; if you tried to make one people would probably just think you were saying "own". You would confuse people. "I ow'n the car" would sound like you own it, not that you owe money on it.

Comment: If you *ow'n* a car, then you probably *own* it, too :)

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Actually, if you ow'n a car, you don't own it yet. :P